# Pandas New Column based on found string in a DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Trying to match an ID value in one DataFrame to a string column in another DataFrame to create a new ID field.

I have two dataframes, one with an text ID column only:

DF1

```
ID
elf
orc
panda
```

And another dataframe with a different ID but a text column that would contain the ID value from the first DataFrame (DF1):

DF2

```
AltID Text
1     The orc killed the dwarf
2     The elf lives in the woods
3     The panda eats bamboo
```

That way I can create New ID column in the second Dataframe (DF2) that would look like this if the text is found:

```
NewID
orc
elf
panda
```

Should I use a lambda function or an np.where()?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

What if it needs to be an exact match?  For instance I have this row of text but don't want to match 'orc'

```
AltID  Text
4      The orchestra played too long
```

and wanted it to output 'None', N/A or something of that nature for the NewID?

Comment: EDIT:

What if it needs to be an exact match?  For instance I have this row of text but don't want to match 'orc'

    AltID  Text
    4        The orchestra played too long

and wanted it to output 'None', N/A or something of that nature for the NewID?

Comment: Right, now on some additional tests it is doing partial matching.  Is there way to avoid partial matches and also include case sensitivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward using `str.extract`:

```
df2['New ID'] = df2.Text.str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(df1.ID)), expand=False)

df2

   AltID                        Text New ID
0      1    The orc killed the dwarf    orc
1      2  The elf lives in the woods    elf
2      3       The panda eats bamboo  panda
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?  Any materials you suggest to read?  Awesome solution.

Comment: @dasvootz Practice, practice, practice. I've answered over a thousand pandas questions by now, so these things tend to come spontaneously to me ;-) By the way, I recommend reading the 10 minutes to pandas tutorial from the official docs. Spend at least an hour on it.

Comment: Done, and makes sense; sometimes the best way to learn is to help others.

Comment: @dasvootz hmm, did the answer not work for you? You have unaccepted the question.

Comment: It is working right now, except in some instances I am getting partial matches.

Comment: @dasvootz Then your [mcve] should have reflected that?

Comment: Fair point, I didn't anticipate that scenario originally.  I'll leave it as accepted as that answer works for the original case.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

A small trick .

```
df2.Text.replace(dict(zip(df1.ID,df1.index)),regex=True).map(df1.ID)
Out[1004]: 
0      orc
1      elf
2    panda
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes, will clear out some votes for you :)

Comment: I am getting partial matches on this one too, didn't see that type of scenario before apologies.